# Android view inflate error

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I want inflate a view from a xml, just like this :

```
View textView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_classify_left, null);
```

But I got a error on the code:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class TextView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:472)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
```

There is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@drawable/item_classify_left_textcolor_selector"
    android:background="@drawable/item_classify_left_background_selector" />
```

I found when I delete the android:textColor and android:background, It work ok. But I really need the selector. There are the selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/main_background_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/item_classify_text_background_normal" />
</selector>
```

How can I solve this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put the **item_classify_left_textcolor_selector.xml** to folder `res/color` ,and use `@color/item_classify_left_textcolor_selector`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/item_classify_left_textcolor_selector"
    android:background="@drawable/item_classify_left_background_selector" />
```